# Route::get with options and function not working properly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wan to use Route::get with route options, function and where. following is my route code:

```
Route::get('/view/{id}', array('uses' =>'BookController@view','as' => 'book.view'), function($id)
{
    die('hello');

})->where('id', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

so when i call url `view/4` it will open 404 page and when i call `view/abc` it will run controller code but in neither case function code is not executing.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you display the controller logic

Comment: there is nothing in controller right now. let's say `echo 'hi';`

Comment: Sorry just noticed why did you attach controller as well as callback function.
You should use either callback or controller

Comment: @Deepak I am planning to put some code in controller and i don't want add much length in route file and that's why i don't want to put controller code in route file (if i can avoid) otherwise i need to do the same. is there any way i can do that?

Comment: Remove the callback first and test it

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP if i remove call back then it will redirect to 404 and i don't want to redirect to 404, i want to open custom url/code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185363/discussion-between-dipen-and-deepak-kumar-t-p).

Comment: That looks "confusing". Why not use two seperate routes?

Answer (score 0):

For routing you already put restriction in "id" variable and it should be string only "->where('id', '[A-Za-z]+');"

So there is no problem here in case you use number it should get you 404

And for controller issue you code it wrongly because you add controller and in same time you write Closure and you have to write only one.

So try this

```
Route::get('/view/{id}', ['uses' =>'BookController@view','as' =>'book.view'])->where('id', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

and for using number try this

```
Route::get('/view/{id}', ['uses' =>'BookController@view','as' =>'book.view']);
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes these both will work but my requirement is different. I want to run custom code when `where()` condition return false. means in my current case if some try interger then function code should work instead of 404 page

Comment: @Dipen Why don't you just use _one_ case, either `closure` or `controller` and decide/check there if `$id` is numeric or alpha?

Comment: @kerbholz My primary goal to avoid controller code from route if it's possible and if we can use id validation in route i don't want to do that in controller. so if condition flied i want to redirect to another url or some custom code and if condition match then execute controller code.